# Change file encoding for PostgreSQL w/Perl

Tags: perl, postgresql, encoding, utf-8

I'm entering large amounts of data into a PostgreSQL database using Perl and the Perl DBI. I have been getting errors as my file is improperly encoded. I have the PostgreSQL encoding set to 'utf8' and used the debian 'file' command to determine that my file has "Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators", and when I run my program the DBI fails due to an "invalid byte sequence". I already added a line in my Perl program to sub the '\r' carriage returns for nothing, but how can I convert my files to 'utf8' or get PostgreSQL to accept my file encoding. Thanks.

Comment: `file` won't reliably detect the encoding. You need to actually *know* what the text encoding is in order to convert it correctly. If you've really got no idea, try to use a tool that does more robust encoding detection than `file`.

Answer (score 1):

When you [connect to PostgreSQL](http://search.cpan.org/~turnstep/DBD-Pg-2.19.3/Pg.pm#pg_enable_utf8_%28boolean%29) using `DBI->connect(..., { pg_enable_utf8 => 1})` then the data used in all modifying DBI calls (SQL `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, everywhere you use placeholders in queries etc) has to be encoded in Perl's internal encoding so that DBI itself can convert to the wire protocol correctly.

There are tons of ways how you can achieve that, and they all depend on how you read the file in the first place. The most basic one is if you use [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) (or one of the methods based directly on it like `IO::File->open`). You can then use Perl's I/O layers (see the `open` link above) and let Perl do that for you. Assuming your file is encoded in UTF-8 already you'll get away with:

```
open(my $fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", "filename");
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  # process query
}
```

This is basically equivalent to opening the file without an encoding layer and converting manually using [`Encode::decode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html#Basic-methods), e.g. like this:

```
open(my $fh, "<", "filename");
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  $line = Encode::decode('UTF-8', $line);
  # process query
}
```

A lot of other modules that receive data from external sources and return it (think of HTTP downloads with `LWP`, for example) return values that have already been converted into Perl's internal encoding.

So what you have to do is:

- Figure out which encoding your file actually uses (try using `iconv` on the shell for that)
- Tell DBI to enable UTF-8
- Open the file with the correct encoding
- Read line(s), process query, repeat